# Gnome-shell cannot adjust screen brightness on dell laptop with intel graphics

Tags: fedora, gnome-shell, brightness

On my dell laptop (XPS 13 developer) running Fedora 21 I am in a situation similar to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182856/screen-brightness-adjustment-not-working-in-ubuntu-14-04), or [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7208/i-cant-adjust-screen-brightness-of-my-laptop-anymore). I can give some more details tough.

Under directory `/sys/class/backlight` I have:

```
dell_backlight/brightness
intel_backlight/brightness
```

Where the first is brought-in, I guess, by `dell_laptop` module, while the second comes from `i915`. Trying to adjust screen brightness works with `intel_backlight` only (by echoing values), while trying to fiddle with other makes no change, with no errors.

The problem is that gnome3 menu settings, and the hotkeys, both try to work around `dell_backlight` (the hotkeys management should be in `dell_wmi` module).

Is there a way to make GNOME use the other, by some setting in gconf maybe? Or just to rewire the hotkeys and the slider to some script?

Edit:

My laptop has a:

```
Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: Dell Device 060a
[...] 
Kernel driver in use: i915
```

This works (with gnome running or not):

```
echo 250 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

This does not:

```
echo 250 > /sys/class/backlight/dell_backlight/brightness
```

I know that gnome-shell is trying to adjust dell_backlight and not intel_backlight, because using the brightness slider in the tray menu, I can read value changes in dell_backlight.

Comment: What graphics card you have? Can you adjust the brightness when Gnome shell isn't running?

Comment: @Braian His graphical card is the build in from Intel (i915) and he can adjust the brightness.

Comment: This is most likely caused by `gnome-settings-daemon` power plugin. Unfortunately I'm not able to help you as I'm using another distro (archlinux, kernel 4.0.1 & gnome 3.16.1) and everything works fine here (my laptop is Dell XPS L502x). I don't even have that `dell_backlight` directory, instead I have `acpi_video0` alongside `intel_backlight`. Though you might want to [try this](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=301935).

Comment: When you press the keys to adjust the brightness, do you get the on-screen brightness display at all? Odds are good that this is basically a bug — in fact, if you have to hack anything here, it is. Check out [this debugging block post](http://hansdegoede.livejournal.com/13889.html), and [file a bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1123661) with the requested info, please. (And thank you. Disclaimer: I work on Fedora.)

Comment: @don_crissti that fixes it; please turn it into an answer and i'll accept it (no idea how i could miss the search result when googling for it!)

Comment: @mattdm i am a packager too ;) yep i see the on-screen overlay with the hotkeys, and it is actually changing the brightness value but of the wrong device. I'll visit bugzilla soon

Comment: @guido - not really as that method doesn't always work... see this [question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/198671)

Comment: @don_crissti mmh, i am still on 3.14 actually; good to know it's just a  temporary fix

Comment: I have exact same problem on Asus F200M with Debian Stretch and Gnome 3, except dell_backlight becomes acpi_video0

Comment: The solution linked by @don_crissti did not work for me so I created a shortcut in Gnome 3 to call `xbacklight -inc (resp -dec) 10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would remove dell_backlight/brightness

I would then add:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=intel"
```

To your grub file then:

```
update-grub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably just shortcut:

`xbacklight -dec 10` & `xbacklight -inc 10` to whatever keys you want. I do this in Fluxbox like so:

```
echo "232 :Exec xbacklight -dec 10" >> ~/.fluxbox/keys
echo "233 :Exec xbacklight -inc 10" >> ~/.fluxbox/keys
```

Comment: no xbacklight and no fluxbox here. i can change brightness from the terminal; i want to fix gnome-shell backlight operation.

Comment: Gnome-shell is similar to mate. Just set a keyboard shortcut (XF86MonBrightnessUp for instance) to `xbacklight -dec 10` [for dimming by 10%, and `xbacklight -inc 10` for incrementing 10%. Doesn't matter what DE you are in.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem with an older Intel-based Dell laptop. The accepted answer here (adding "acpi_backlight=intel" into the GRUB config) did not work for me. What finally did work was a different GRUB setting.

Open `/etc/default/grub` for editing.

Find the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` and add `pcie_aspm=force acpi_backlight=native` to it so that the whole thing looks liek

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force acpi_backlight=native"
```

Then run `sudo update-grub` and reboot.